# Is it possible to lock a file in svn so that no one can work on that expect the one who locked

Tags: asp.net, svn

As i get vexed with of lot of issues using `SVN` is it possible to make a file locked so that the file should not be accessed by others expect for the one who locked out. Is there such functionality in `SVN`.

Comment: while svn lock does that, other people can break the lock... which makes sense if someone forgot to unlock and is not available. you can, however, write server side hooks to prevent other from unlocking files

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there's [svn lock](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.locking.html). A locked file can be checked out by other users, but only the lock owner can check in changes to it.

However, it's rarely a good idea to use locking. It might be a bit more convenient for the lock owner, but it slows down anyone else who needs to work on the file. The usual workflow of merging conflicts when they occur (what's called 'optimistic locking' in other contexts) is usually faster and smoother overall, and more so for larger teams.

Comment: I tried as per below clicking on the file `Selected Subversion -> Subversion properties there i select the property svn needs lock` but this is not allowing me to edit the file is it the correct process

Comment: That's not a question about Subversion, that's a question about whatever tool it is you're using to access Subversion. We have no idea what that tool is, so we can't help you.

Comment: I make a general `Lock ` but that didn't work. I am using `SVN` with `.NET`

Comment: You still haven't told us what tool you're using. 'svn' means the command-line client, but it's obviously not that if it has menus. .net is a platform. Do you understand the difference between tools and platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's conveniently called `svn lock`:

```
svn help lock
lock: Lock working copy paths or URLs in the repository, so that
no other user can commit changes to them.
usage: lock TARGET...
```

Also see [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.locking.html)

Comment: I tried as per below clicking on the file `Selected Subversion -> Subversion properties there i select the property svn needs lock` but this is not allowing me to edit the file is it the correct process